# Unable to create user document inside _users DB

Tags: couchdb

I am getting unexpected error suddenly in my production setup (while creating users document inside _users DB)

```
{
    "error": "EXIT",
    "reason": "{{badmatch,[]},\n [{couch_query_servers,new_process,3},\n {couch_query_servers,lang_proc,3},\n {couch_query_servers,handle_call,3},\n {gen_server,handle_msg,5},\n {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}"
}
```

This is my document structure and It was working fine since last 2years

```
{"_id": "org.couchdb.user:name","name": "name","roles": [],"type": "user","password": "password"}
```

I really appreciate your help to fix my issue

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution. In my **_users** table there was a design document created **_design/X12635**. After I deleted the document, It started working fine.

```
{
   "_id": "_design/X12635",
   "_rev": "1-12bc5863e7f65bad6ddf51c1748c3e42",
   "language": "erlang",
   "validate_doc_update": "fun ({NewDoc}, OldDoc, UserCtx, SecObj)->\n\t%%Covers CVE-2017-12635\n\tRoles = proplists:lookup_all(<<\"roles\">>,NewDoc),\n\tcase length(Roles) < 2 of\n\t\ttrue -> ok;\n\t\tfalse ->throw({[{<<\"forbidden\">>, <<\"You can’t hack roles,sorry\">>}]})\n\tend,\n\t1\nend."
}
```

After getting @Flimzy comment, I spent some more time and found an alternate solution for it. I again restore the above design document **_design/X12635** and added below configuration in my **CouchDB 1.6.1**

```
Section : native_query_servers  
Option : erlang 
Value : {couch_native_process, start_link, []}
```

Enabling ***erlang*** might affect security, better to upgrade the **CouchDB 1.6.1** to latest version